# org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/ids

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I've deployed 3 node kafka v.3.2.3 with externl 3 node zookeeper v.3.8.0 on kubernetes v 1.26.

My Kafka config:

```
advertised.listeners=INTERNAL://10.244.1.110:9091,EXTERNAL://kf-test-b5s8uz:9092
auto.create.topics.enable=false
broker.id=1
compression.type=snappy
default.replication.factor=3
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
listener.security.protocol.map=EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9091,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=2000
log.message.timestamp.type=LogAppendTime
min.insync.replicas=2
num.network.threads=8
num.partitions=8num.replica.fetchers=4
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests=100
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.connect=zk-test-kp1hh3
zookeeper.set.acl=true
```

My ZK config:

```
#CONFIGURATION OPTIONS FOR ZOOKEEPER SERVER
        
#MINIMUM CONFIGURATION
clientPort=2181
dataDir=/data/data
tickTime=2000
        
#ADVANCED CONFIGURATION
dataLogDir=/data/txnlogs
#globalOutstandingLimit=
#preAllocSize=
#snapCount=
#maxClientCnxs=
#clientPortAddress=
#minSessionTimeout=
#maxSessionTimeout=
autopurge.purgeInterval=6
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=
#syncEnabled=
        
#CLUSTER OPTIONS
#electionAlg=
initLimit=10
#leaderServes=
syncLimit=5
#cnxTimeout=
4lw.commands.whitelist=*
        
#UNSAFE OPTIONS
#forceSync=
#skipACL=
#quorumListenOnAllIPs=

#AUTH OPTIONS
authProvider.1=org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.SASLAuthenticationProvider
jaasLoginRenew=3600000
requireClientAuthScheme=sasl
enforce.auth.enabled=false
#enforce.auth.schemes=
allowSaslFailedClients=true
server.1=zk-test-kp1hh3-0.zk-test-kp1hh3.dev:2888:3888
server.2=zk-test-kp1hh3-1.zk-test-kp1hh3.dev:2888:3888
server.3=zk-test-kp1hh3-2.zk-test-kp1hh3.dev:2888:3888
```

Kafka jaas config file:

```
// Kafka server authentication
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="admin"
   password="Password1"
   user_admin="Password1"
   user_bob="Password1";
};
// Zookeeper client authentication
Client {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
   username="client1"
   password="Password1";
};
```

Zookeeper jaas config file:

```
Server {
   org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required
   user_admin="Password1"
   user_client1="Password1";
};
```

I want to replace 'client1' user in both Zookeeper and Kafka jaas files with new user, but after changing the username on both Zookeeper and kafka, I receive an error on Kafka broker:

```
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,261] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,751] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ kafka org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoAuthException: KeeperErrorCode = NoAuth for /brokers/ids                                                                                                                                                                                                                      │
│ kafka     at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:120)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│ kafka     at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:54)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ kafka     at kafka.zookeeper.AsyncResponse.maybeThrow(ZooKeeperClient.scala:566)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│ kafka     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createRecursive(KafkaZkClient.scala:1728)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│ kafka     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.makeSurePersistentPathExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1626)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│ kafka     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1(KafkaZkClient.scala:1618)                                                                                                                                                                                                                               │
│ kafka     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.$anonfun$createTopLevelPaths$1$adapted(KafkaZkClient.scala:1618)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ kafka     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ kafka     at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.createTopLevelPaths(KafkaZkClient.scala:1618)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ kafka     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.initZkClient(KafkaServer.scala:501)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ kafka     at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:203)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ kafka     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│ kafka     at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,754] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,849] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)                                                                                                                                                                                                             │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,963] INFO Session: 0x100537fc5e80001 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,964] INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x100537fc5e80001 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,965] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)                                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,972] INFO App info kafka.server for 2 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,973] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:02,973] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        │
│ kafka [2023-05-31 14:23:03,052] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

How can I replace user for Zookeeper client in Kafka?

I would be appreciate for any help.